# How to handle displaying dynamic global attributes in emberjs

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I want to have a header title that gets change depending on what controller is being used.

Here is my application template:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="page-header">
      {{#if pageTitle}}
        <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
      {{/if}}
    </div>
    <div class="span12">
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the page title is set it should display it.

Now say I have a posts controller I tried:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  pageTitle: 'Posts'
});
```

which didn't work.

I also tried setting it up in the route like:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('pageTitle', 'Posts');
  }
});
```

I'm sure this is very simple, I'm just not seeing the best way of doing what I want to do.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be setting the `pageTitle` value on your `ApplicationController`, as the value is used outside of the outlet it's context is the outermost controller in this case application.

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller) {
    this.controllerFor("application").set('pageTitle', 'Posts');
  }
});
```